# connecting two divs using jsplumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb to my project. I mentioned my sample below. when I drag and drop divs, divs should appear with anchor points. anchors points can be connecting each other. in my sample I did drag and drop part. but I am unable to complete the rest of the work. please check my sample and get an idea.

I am using jsplumb to my project. I mentioned my sample below. when I drag and drop divs, divs should appear with anchor points. anchors points can be connecting each other. in my sample I did drag and drop part. but I am unable to complete rest of the work. please check my sample and get the idea.

```js
    jsPlumb.ready(function() {

        jsPlumb.Defaults.Container=$("#dropArea");
        jsPlumb.Defaults.PaintStyle = { strokeStyle:"palevioletred", lineWidth:2, 
        dashstyle: '3 3'};
        jsPlumb.Defaults.EndpointStyle = { radius:7, fillStyle:"palevioletred" };
        jsPlumb.importDefaults({Connector : [ "Bezier", { curviness:50 } ]});


        jsPlumb.connect({
    connector: ["Straight"],
    source:"element",
    target:"element",
    anchor: ["Left", "Right"],
    endpoint:"Dot"
    });

        jsPlumb.setContainer($('#dropArea'));
        var i = 1;
        $(".element").draggable        ({
            helper : 'clone',
            cursor : 'pointer',
            tolerance : 'fit',
            revert : true
        });

        $("#dropArea").droppable        ({
            accept: '.element',
            containment: 'dropArea',

            drop: function (e, ui) {
                droppedElement = ui.helper.clone();
                ui.helper.remove();
                $(droppedElement).removeAttr("class");
                jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);

                var newAgent = $('<div>').attr('id', 'pro' + i).addClass('pro');
                newAgent.text('Element ' + i);
                $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "dropArea"});
                $('#dropArea').append(newAgent);

                jsPlumb.draggable(newAgent, {
                    containment: 'parent'                });
                i++;
            }
        });

        $("#dropArea").on('click', '.pro', function (e) {
            i++;
            var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', 'state' + i).addClass('section').
            text('Section '+ (i-1));

            var title = $('<div>').addClass('title');
            var connect = $('<div>').addClass('connector').
            text('Click here to drag');

            newState.css({
                'top': e.pageY,
                'left': e.pageX            });

            newState.append(title);
            newState.append(connector);

            $(this).append(newState);

            jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
                anchor: 'Continuous'            });

            jsPlumb.makeSource(connector, {
                anchor: 'Continuous'            });

            newState.dblclick(function (e) {
                jsPlumb.detachAllConnections($(this));
                $(this).remove();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

        });
    });
```

```css
       
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
        * {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }
        #dropArea {
            position: relative;
            resize: both;
            margin-left: 180px;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            width: 800px;
            height: 650px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .title {
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: move;
        }
        .connector {
            font-size:10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .element {
            border: 1px solid gray;
            text-align: center;
            width: 170px;
            height: 75px;
            background-color: lightpink;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .pro {
            border: 1px solid gray;
            text-align: center;
            width: 170px;
            height: 75px;
            background-color:  lightpink;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .section {
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: 200;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #ddddff;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.7.13/js/jsplumb.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="element" id="cId">
</div>
<div id="dropArea">
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Keyur Ramoliya , can you help me :)